# Need to Improve performance of sql queries

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 3 table a,b,c.

```
select * from a

select * from b where aid in (select id from a)

select * from c where bid in (select Id from b where aid in (select id from a))
```

These queries in sp and working fine but as performance I need to optimise these.
Could you please suggest how do I improve perfomance, or any tools available to 
optimise sql queries.

Thanks .

Comment: "working fine" - so why do you think you have a performance issue?

Comment: working fine means giving proper result, but in third query i am passing two sub queries. in that case id of a then id of b then that will execute so taking time is there any alternate way.

Comment: I would assume that sql server 2008 has a good enough optimizer to figure out to implement your ridiculously inefficient sql code using the inner joins that Tudor Constantin suggested. So, I would be more willing to bet that you will see a performance improvement by specifying proper indexes as Anders UP suggested. Whatever the case is, please let us know what happened after you have tried these suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could rewrite the queries using `INNER JOIN`:

```
select * from c 
INNER JOIN b ON b.id = c.bid 
INNER JOIN a ON a.id = b.aid
```

if you have indexes on id, bid and aid all should be fine

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons why your queries are slow. From what you describe a few starting points could be:

- Indexes missing or incorrect. At the very least you must have indexes on columns that you join or filter on.
- Statistics for indexes must be up-to-date
- Indexes could in some cases benefit from having more fields as included columns.
- Correct amount of data returned - both in terms of columns and rows. If you return too much, you'll flood the various buffers and reduce overall performance.

You might want to use the Tuning Advisor and/or SQL Server Profiler - both avaialble in the Performance Tools menu under your SQL Server folder in startup.

Also, learning the Management Studios reporting possibilities, and getting acquainted with execution plans are good starting points.

For the more advanced learners, start including statistics for query I/O (in Management Studios Query Window), using the Windows Performance Monitor to keep an eye on relevant SQL Server counters, etc. A good explanation to some of them can be found here: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2005/sql-server-performance-monitor-coutners/

Answer (score 0):

Can you express your queries like:

```
select * from b where b.aid = a.id and a.somefield = 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using exists instead of IN:s. If there is allot of data that can help:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    a

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    b 
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 
            NULL 
        FROM 
            a
        WHERE
            a.id=b.aid
    )

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    c 
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 
            NULL 
        FROM 
            b
        WHERE
            c.bid=b.Id
            AND EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 
                    NULL 
                FROM
                    a
                WHERE
                    b.aid=a.id
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid usage of *. Mention explicitly the column names.
2. Use Non Clustered Index for the tables with large number of records.
3. Use Joins instead of Sub Queries.
4. Use "**Set NoCount On**" in the Stored Procedures.
5. You can use Temp tables. Insert the required data and execute it finally. Don;t forget to drop it before you exit the stored procedure.